# Invalid object name 'F0DEMOTBLCARI'. Error

Tags: c#

```
namespace TopluCari
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private String ConStr = "Server=.;Database=12;User Id=sa;Password=v1234;";
        private DataTable initialDataTable = new DataTable();
        private DataTable currentDataTable = new DataTable();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // DataGridView olay dinleyicisi ekleyin
            dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Verileri çekmek için SQL sorgusu
            string queryy = "SELECT IND, KISAAD FROM TBLFIRMA";

            // Veritabanı bağlantısı oluştur
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();

                // Verileri çekmek için bir SqlDataAdapter kullan
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryy, connection))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    // ComboBox'a verileri eklemek
                    comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "KISAAD"; // ComboBox'ta görünen metin
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "IND"; // ComboBox'tan seçilen değer
                }
            }
            comboBox1.Items.Add("101");
            // ComboBox'ta varsayılan seçeneği ayarla (en sonuncu öğe)
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;

            // ComboBox'tan seçilen değeri alın
            string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(); // Seçilen değeri alın

            // Değerin başına "F0" ekleyin ve boşlukları kaldırın
            string formattedValue = "F0" + selectedValue.Trim() + "TBLCARI";

            // Eğer selectedValue null ise, bir hata oluşmasını önlemek için varsayılan bir değer atayabilirsiniz
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedValue))
            {
                formattedValue = "F0TBLCARI"; // Varsayılan değeri atayın
            }

            string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM " + formattedValue + ";";

            // Başlangıç verilerini yükle
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(initialDataTable);
                    currentDataTable = initialDataTable.Copy();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataTable;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
            string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                    // Değişiklikleri kaydet
                    adapter.Update(currentDataTable);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Değişiklikleri geri al
            currentDataTable.Clear();
            currentDataTable = initialDataTable.Copy();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataTable;
        }

        // DataGridView hücre değeri değiştiğinde bu olay tetiklenir
        private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Değişen hücrenin arka plan rengini yeşil yap
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = textBox1.Text.Trim();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
                string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    // TextBox doluysa, sadece TextBox'ta yazan metni arar
                    query += " WHERE KOD1 LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(filteredDataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredDataTable;
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = textBox2.Text.Trim();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
                string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    // TextBox doluysa, sadece TextBox'ta yazan metni arar
                    query += " WHERE KOD2 LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(filteredDataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredDataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = textBox3.Text.Trim();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
                string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    // TextBox doluysa, sadece TextBox'ta yazan metni arar
                    query += " WHERE KOD3 LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(filteredDataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredDataTable;
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = textBox4.Text.Trim();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
                string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    // TextBox doluysa, sadece TextBox'ta yazan metni arar
                    query += " WHERE KOD4 LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(filteredDataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredDataTable;
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = textBox5.Text.Trim();
            string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    // TextBox doluysa, sadece TextBox'ta yazan metni arar
                    query += " WHERE KOD5 LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(filteredDataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredDataTable;
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = textBox6.Text.Trim();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
                string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    // TextBox doluysa, sadece TextBox'ta yazan metni arar
                    query += " WHERE FIRMAADI LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(filteredDataTable);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredDataTable;
                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ComboBox'tan seçilen değeri alın
            string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;

            // Değerin başına "F0" ekleyin ve boşlukları kaldırın
            string formattedValue = "F0" + selectedValue.Trim() + "TBLCARI";

            // Eğer selectedValue null ise, bir hata oluşmasını önlemek için varsayılan bir değer atayabilirsiniz
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
            {
                formattedValue = "F0TBLCARI"; // Varsayılan değeri atayın
            }

            string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM " + formattedValue + ";";

            // Verileri çekerek DataGridView'i güncelleyin
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                {
                    currentDataTable.Clear(); // Önceki verileri temizle
                    adapter.Fill(currentDataTable); // Yeni verileri çek
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataTable; // DataGridView'i güncelle
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I get the error in the title with this code I wrote.
F0DEMOTBLCARI is the demo Company name here. What I want to put there is the IND information of that selected company.

With this code, I want to create a query with the company information retrieved from the database in the combobox and correct the current accounts of the selected company in bulk.

In the form, the company in the combobox must first be selected, and then information according to the selected company should appear on the datagridview screen. Whenever a company is changed from the combobox, the datagridview section should be cleared and information based on the newly selected company should appear. The part I need help with is that no information is available depending on the company selected in the combobox and it gives the error in the title. Could you help?

At the same time, I am thinking of adding a button that will transfer this information to Excel. I have not written any code for it yet. My priority is for it to work as I explained above.

Since it was a small program, I couldn't pay attention to security and basics, and at the same time, I just started coding and learning. I would be very happy if you write what the code needs in terms of operation and make suggestions.

Comment: There is not table with the name `F0DEMOTBLCARI` in your database ...

Comment: And btw something like `query += " WHERE KOD2 LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";`  is *very* insecure as it widely opens the door to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries instead ...

Comment: Yes, there is no such table. The IND of the company named "Demo" is 101. While he should have written this IND there, he wrote Demo and got an error. I need to know why he wrote the company name.

Comment: that `formattedValue` being concatenated into `FORM` should be the culprit. we have no clue why it defaults to that and how the database looked like. your question have lots of text but does not fulfil [mcve].

Comment: Because you do `string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;` and then `string query = "SELECT IND, FIRMAADI, KOD1, KOD2, KOD3, KOD4, KOD5 FROM F0" + selectedValue + "TBLCARI;";` Ie, `comboBox1.Text` is the text displayed in the combobox (in your example obviously "DEMO") and not the value of that item ...

Comment: Thank you for your attention. How can I fix?

Comment: create empty table with that name and see what happens.

Comment: take `comboBox1.Value` instead? Like you do in the first query?

Comment: 'comboBox1.ValueMember = "IND";'

This should be the value you need to write